# Dynamodb's PutItem update using condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to accomplish batch update into DynamoDB. I'm trying to determine if I can put a condition in my batch update that says if one of the column equalling a value (which evaluates to true), should update the items if not, do not update. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a conditional expression on a single item update to make the update fail if the condition is not met. However it will not fail an entire batch, just the single update. The batch update response would contain information on which updates succeeded and which failed

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [DynamoDB transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html). It has the conditional expressions you are looking for and all or nothing batch updates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for conditional expressions, check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).

You should use UpdateItem, which edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table if it does not already exist.

e.g. copied from aws doc,

The following example performs an UpdateItem operation. It attempts to reduce the Price of a product by 75—but the condition expression prevents the update if the current Price is below 500:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id": {"N": "456"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET Price = Price - :discount" \
    --condition-expression "Price > :limit" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json
```

Table ProductCatalog is like this,

```
{
    "Id": { "N": "456"},
    "Price": {"N": "650"},
    "ProductCategory": {"S": "Sporting Goods"}
}
```

and values.json likem this,

```
{
    ":discount": { "N": "75"},
    ":limit": {"N": "500"}
}
```

Here initially price is 650, with conditional expression you're trying to reduce price by 75 if Price is greater than 500. so first two run of update-item should will work, and on third run since price is reduced to 500 (which is not greater than 500) run will fail.

Answer (score -3):

It's possible to do it, by using conditional expression for filter expression. But please don't do it.

DynamoDB is a key-value NoSQL. It means that you can get the right data by keys only. If you do the filter, it will loop through a lot of records and slow down you app.
You can check this article:
[5 things that you should know about DynamoDB](https://problemlover.com/5-things-that-you-should-know-before-using-dynamodb-for-your-project/)

So when you CRUD the data, the recommended way to interact with data is by key. I can translate it to pseudo code like this:

```
GET: SELECT * FROM THE TABLE WHERE Id ='SampleId'
UPDATE: UPDATE THE ITEM WHERE id = 'SampleId'
DELETE: DELETETHE ITEM WHERE id = 'SampleId'
```

To satisfy your needs, you need to use elastic search to get the right items, after that you can update the data by key.

Comment: The key I am using is a global index for the condition. Would it still loop through the entire dataset?

Comment: No. PutItem requires the primary key of the item to update so it will not loop through the entire dataset. The PutItem function doesn't even support filter expressions